# unable to update data using Axios put request

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, backend, mern

I am creating a MERN Project . It is requiring to update a data from the backend using a put request . The payload in Network after the put request says

{id: "64b7f150ae89eb4b762466ce", title: "Jannat 100% PetFriendly Pool villa with LakeView",…}
address
:
"Pimplad Nasik, Maharashtra, India"
checkIn
:
12
checkOut
:
14
description
:
"Jannat blends the most luxurious backdrop of your fantasy with nature’s incredible marvels to create a tranquil utopia that caters to your comfort where Breakfast is complimentary! This 3Bed pool villa in Nashik is a hidden paradise waiting to dazzle you with its tranquil charm.\n"
extraInfo
:
"This villa offers 3 spacious bedrooms and ensuite bathrooms in 2 bedrooms, giving you ample space to have "
id
:
"64b7f150ae89eb4b762466ce"
maxGuests
:
1
perks
:
["WiFi", "Parking", "TV", "Pets", "Radio", "Entrance"]
title
:
"Jannat 100% PetFriendly Pool villa with LakeView"

This is the requested payload in the network . Here i am trying to update the description title but the response headers say something like this .

"Cannot PUT /places"

The function responsible for Put Request is here below

```
async function savePlace(e)
    {
        const placeData = {title , address , addedPhotos ,
            description ,perks ,extraInfo ,
            checkIn ,checkOut ,maxGuests }
        e.preventDefault();
        if(id)
        {
            //update
            await axios.put('/places',{id, ...placeData})
            setRedirect(true)
        }
        else{        
            // new place
        await axios.post('/places',placeData)
        setRedirect(true)
    }
```

The backend api for the post request is here below

```
app.put('/places ', async(req,res)=>{
    
    const {token} = req.cookies ; 
    const { id,
        title , address , addedPhotos , description,
        perks , extraInfo , checkIn , checkOut , maxGuests 
    } = req.body; 
    
    jwt.verify(token , jwtSecret ,{} , async(err,userData)=>{
        if(err) throw err;

        
       
        
        const placeDoc = await Place.findById(id);

        if(userData.id === placeDoc.owner.toString()){
            placeDoc.set({
            title , address , photos:addedPhotos , description,
            perks , extraInfo , checkIn , checkOut , maxGuests

            })
            await placeDoc.save()
            res.json({placeDoc})
        }
    })
    })
```

The console says

"

settle.js:19 Uncaught (in promise)
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code
:
"ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
config
:
{transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}
message
:
"Request failed with status code 404"
name
:
"AxiosError"
request
:
XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: true, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
response
:
{data: '\n\n\n<meta char…y>\n

```
Cannot PUT /places
```

\n\n\n', status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}
stack
:
"AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404\n    at settle (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=255f0134:1189:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=255f0134:1417:7)"
[[Prototype]]
:
Error
savePlace   @   PlacesFormPage.jsx:83

"

I am trying to update the title in my data so that the data gets updated in the backend .
when i was changing the title in the frontend i expected it to be changed and redirected to the page where all the data was to be shown , but instead it is giving this 404 error of places not found .

Please look into this .

Comment: Did you add a proxy for your backend?

Comment: There is a trailing space in the back-end `"/places "` put route definition. This might be the cause of the issue. Does removing it fix your issue?

Comment: if this error resolves my issue then Im going to quit development man

Comment: @3limin4t0r bro you saved my whole life. If only you'd have come a bit earlier it wouldn't have cost me 4 days of life.